# GetUninitializedObject in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

First, the situation. I am doing school project. I have to implement my own clone function. It takes object as argument, creates exact copy and returns it. Function declaration:

```
Object clone(Object obj);
```

Problem is that obj.getClass() doesn't have to have appropriate constructor. For example private constructor that takes 3 arguments. So I don't know how should I create objects. Constructor.newInstance(arguments) won't work. And I don't know any other way. So I was wondering if there isn't such method as GetUninitializedObject, which is in C#. Suggestions for different solutions are welcomed.

Thanks in advance

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can get constructors of a class and also their parameter types. you can read from here:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html
if a class hasn't any public constructors, there's nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

In Java your best options are either to require a public no-args constructor and require setters (often referred to as a `Bean`), or use Java's built in Serialization via `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`.  You can also use `Object.clone()` to do this, although it's discouraged by many Java experts (for example, Josh Bloch warns against it in "Effective Java")